# "Time warp hiccups" in the tag filtered newest questions tab?

Tags: discussion, bug

From time to time I notice that there are strange *"time warp hiccups"* in the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag filtered newest question tab. After clicking the tag filter button, to e.g. return from a question to the selected tab, it shows the questions from hours ago as *"newest"*:

[image]

I well know that there are newer questions, because I just came back from one at that moment.

Did anyone else experience this recently?

---

In case it should matter, I'm using *Chrome Version 42.0.2311.152 m*. But I'm almost sure it's no caching problem. Looks more like a switch to an unsynchronized DB server or so.

Comment: Getting this too. 5h old questions right now on the 'newest' page.

Comment: @Mat I'm experiencing this more and more frequent recently. Usually it goes away after a few minutes. Looks like some database synch problem between distributed servers.

Comment: this could be effect of [meta-tag:migration] - at Programmers,questions  migrated from other sites show up exactly as you describe

Comment: @gnat I don't really see how this comes from _migration_. It looks like a bug (synch hiccup) for me.

Comment: This is a typical weekend mishap, has been around for years.  I assume it has to do something with maintenance upsetting the caches.   Maybe the SEDE data copy, that's just a wild guess.  It always clears itself up in an hour, give or take.

Comment: @HansPassant The weird observation is, that it happens more frequently in the recent time. I've been desisting to ask this question for a quite long time of observing the behavior. It was creeping in for a few weeks or even months now.

Comment: I'm not sure it's just confined to this scenario. I've seen users post questions/comments/answers hours _after_ their 'last seen' timestamp on a few occasions - never thought to take screen-shots though.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a case of [caching issues](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) but may be related to [Elastic search problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233740/search-results-are-old-out-of-date).