# Front page caches too agressively

Tags: bug, new-nav, caching

The front page (http://stackoverflow.com) frequently shows me its state from a few hours ago. Steps to reproduce:

1. Have visited http://stackoverflow.com a few times before (shouldn't be too hard).
2. Visit above URL again.
3. The address bar will change to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive.
4. Open a random question by clicking its title.
5. Click the StackOverflow logo above the question to return to the front page (the URL mentioned at #1).
6. The address bar will change to the URL mentioned at #3.

What I now expect to see, is the list of questions I saw at my last visit to the front page (#2) - or a fresher list. Yet it shows me a very outdated front page, namely that of #1 (a few *hours* old).

The headers of #2 show `Cache-Control: private, max-age=0`. At #5, *no* new HTTP request is made, the page is served from cache.

Comment: Possibly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294466/time-warp-hiccups-in-the-tag-filtered-newest-questions-tab

Comment: @pi yeah, looks related. This one is quite persistent for me though.

Comment: I've noticed that behavior on weekends primarily, but not certainly reproducible.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300233/new-homepage-navigation-breaks-back-button

Comment: That looks more like it @Joe, thanks.

Comment: It's happened for me every time now, on [new-nav].  Go to my tag, click on question, back, it's outdated, always, 100%. Chrome 44.  And it's not showing me the page I *just clicked away from* - it's showing me something much older - so it's not strictly a cache issue.