# Wrong information presented in question list

Tags: bug, specific-question, user-interface

I just saw this question in the question list:
[image]

And noticed it had a very similar title to one I'd seen asked yesterday.  I went to look, to see if it was the same asker posting the same question again, but it linked [to the question asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700833/parsing-custom-json-response-with-json-net), not to one asked by "Bob", 9 minutes ago.

Funnily enough, the link behind "Bob" points to the [correct user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3977196/chaos).

What's going on?

Comment: Users are allowed to check their display name...

Comment: Yeah the username bit I can understand - it's the time discrepancy that's the odd bit

Comment: Feels more like you are experiencing [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300445/front-page-caches-too-agressively) combined with the user changing the displayname...

Comment: @rene Yes - that would explain it

Comment: Maybe this is [related as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197055/live-refresh-shows-modified-on-tagged-questions-even-when-unmodified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user changed their display name quite recently.

The question list is heavily cached. Wait a while, it'll catch up soon enough.

The relative time issue is indeed a problem, already reported on Meta.SE: [The new navigation only shows the date asked, also when modified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260263/the-new-navigation-only-shows-the-date-asked-also-when-modified), and people have been able to get the site in a state where older posts are being shown as 'new', see [Front page caches too agressively](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300445/front-page-caches-too-agressively)

Comment: Heavily cached to the point where a question asked _19 hours ago_ can show up as being asked _9 minutes ago_?

Comment: The question was also active recently (comments).

Comment: It still wasn't asked 9 minutes ago though - had it said 19 hours ago, I wouldn't have bothered clicking through on the assumption it was the one I looked at yesterday.  Shouldn't it say "active 9 mins ago" or "modified 9 mins ago" etc?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I did find a Meta.SE bug report for the timestamp issue.

Comment: Great, thanks - looks like @rene has found another, up above too

Comment: Just for info - search shows it correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=parsing%20custom%20json

Comment: @JamesThorpe: what URL are you seeing this at? On a [tag specific list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/json?show=all&sort=newest) I see the correct info.

Comment: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=recentlyactive) - tends to be the only one I ever look at.  That particular question has disappeared from it now