# Suddenly I'm only seeing hours-old questions on Stack Overflow's Newest Questions list

Tags: support

When I look at the Newest Questions page, I'm only seeing things from eight hours ago. This is using Google Chrome 44 on Linux. Similar to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294466/time-warp-hiccups-in-the-tag-filtered-newest-questions-tab) but I'm not filtering on any tags (in case that's a factor). I got to the Questions page by clicking the Questions box/link from within a question (the orange one). The condition survived several page refreshes.

**Edit:** ...and we're back with the current content again. Brief hiccup of some kind? I was thrown because I saw a title I'd seen hours ago and thought "User posted their question a second time."

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you use the back button to get on that page? I remember seeing this reported at least twice before if so. [one example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300764/73226)

Comment: It's appearing frequently every Saturday for me. I've once [asked about this already](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294466/time-warp-hiccups-in-the-tag-filtered-newest-questions-tab). But nobody seems to care much. I'd suspect a server side caching problem, since I've had that again today several times, and it lead back to the same question on top.

Comment: @MartinSmith: No, I didn't, I clicked the Questions link when viewing a question. The problem also survived several page refreshes.